# Vertex cover problem modification such that every vertex is connected to the set, NP-Hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, np-hard, np

Being new to complexity problems, I've met a question that is quite similar to the [Vertex Cover Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) and I am not sure if this one is NP-Hard. We know that the vertex cover problem is the following: given a graph $(V, E)$, selecting a set of vertices $S$ such that every edge $e \in E$ in the graph is connected to some vertices in $S$. The problem of minimizing the vertex cover problem is a well-known NP-hard problem.

My question is the following: given a graph $(V, E)$, selecting a set of vertices $S$ such that every node $v \in V$ is either in $S$ or connected to the nodes in $S$. Is this problem of minimizing the set of $S$ NP-Hard? This problem seems to be quite intuitive after learning the vertex cover problem, but I didn't find a similar question after searching. I apologize if I asked duplicated questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called the [Dominating Set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set), and it is indeed NP-hard. In fact, it's in some sense harder than Vertex Cover, since it's not fixed parameter tractable (FPT) with respect to the solution size $k$.

Comment: Fixed parameter tractable in which parameter? The size?

Comment: @6005: That's right, I updated the answer. Thanks!